# Read ftr file into R

Tags: python, r, feather

I want to open a `.ftr` file in R. [not a `.feather` file!].

But neither the feather package nor arrow one do the job e.g. both

```
ex1 <- feather::read_feather("bla.ftr")
ex2 <- arrow::read_feather("bla.ftr")
```

do the job.

The arrow approach gives the following error message:

```
Error in ipc___feather___Reader__Read(self, columns) : 
  NotImplemented: LZ4 codec support not built
```

Is there any chance to read in a `.ftr` file?

For your reference, I created the `.ftr` file in python with `pandas` as in

```
bla.to_feather("bla.ftr")
```

with `bla` being a pandas.DataFrame

Comment: The answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63096059/how-to-get-the-arrow-package-for-r-with-lz4-support) show how to build `arrow` with `LZ4` support. This would be preferred to recreating the file in a different format. The `LZ4` format is often worth taking advantage of.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to the compression of the file. I tried pyarrow instead of pandas opting for the 'uncompressed' file and it worked with R. I think pandas call pyarrow, but I don't know if you can pass the argument compression in pandas. In pyarrow this is the code:

```
feather.write_feather(df, file_path, compression='uncompressed')
```