# How to get the arrow package for R with lz4 support?

Tags: r, apache-arrow

The `R` package `arrow` installed with `install.packages('arrow')` does not have `lz4` support:

```
codec_is_available('lz4')
# [1] FALSE
```

The package version is:

```
packageVersion('arrow')
# [1] ‘0.17.1’
```

This is on Ubuntu 20.04.

How can I get an `R` `arrow` package with `lz4` support?

Comment: Which version of the package are you using (1.0?)?  How do you determine that lz4 support is missing?

Comment: @UweL.Korn I edited my question to address these two issues.

Comment: Can you try building from source with `LIBARROW_MINIMAL=false`, as described here? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arrow/vignettes/install.html

Comment: @NickODell It is building now, and it should solve my issue. Feel free to post this as an answer to my question.

Comment: Consider defining `ARROW_WITH_LZ4="ON"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arrow/vignettes/install.html), you can use `export LIBARROW_MINIMAL=false` when building from source to make a build which supports compression:

> You can also install the R package from a git checkout:
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/apache/arrow
> cd arrow/r
> R CMD INSTALL .
> ```
>
> If you don't already have the Arrow C++ libraries on your system, when
> installing the R package from source, it will also download and build
> the Arrow C++ libraries for you. To speed installation up, you can set
>
> ```
> export LIBARROW_BINARY=true
> ```
>
> to look for C++ binaries prebuilt for your Linux distribution/version.
> Alternatively, you can set
>
> ```
> export LIBARROW_MINIMAL=false
> ```
>
> to build the Arrow libraries with optional features **such as
> compression libraries** enabled. This will increase the build time but
> provides many useful features. Prebuilt binaries are built with this
> flag enabled, so you get the full functionality by using them as well.

Comment: I would add that, at least on Linux, `install_arrow` can reinstall arrow assuming `arrow` is already installed.

Then `install_arrow(binary = FALSE, minimal = FALSE)` will rebuild the package from source (since `binary == FALSE`) with the optional dependencies.

Comment: Is `install_arrow` provided by the R arrow package?

Comment: Yes, see the discussion just below the docs you quoted.

Comment: `install_arrow(binary = FALSE, minimal = FALSE)` rebuilt the package but did not fix this issue for me on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: in fact, `codec_is_available` reports `FALSE` for both LZ4 and ZSTD.... so that's pretty useless in working with `pyarrow`

Comment: Also doesn't work for my system (Ubuntu 20.04). I've tried different ways of installing/compiling arrow and it never built if with lz4 support (yes, libs are installed; yes, python can use lz4)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [Nick ODell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/530160/nick-odell) did not work for me, running ubuntu 18.04 in a docker container.

What worked:
(1) First install libraries mentioned under the subheading `Debian GNU/Linux and Ubuntu:` here: https://arrow.apache.org/install/
(2) Install r-arrow normally

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y -V ca-certificates lsb-release wget
wget https://apache.bintray.com/arrow/$(lsb_release --id --short | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')/apache-arrow-archive-keyring-latest-$(lsb_release --codename --short).deb
sudo apt install -y -V ./apache-arrow-archive-keyring-latest-$(lsb_release --codename --short).deb
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y -V libarrow-dev # For C++
sudo apt install -y -V libarrow-glib-dev # For GLib (C)
sudo apt install -y -V libarrow-dataset-dev # For Arrow Dataset C++
sudo apt install -y -V libarrow-flight-dev # For Flight C++
# Notes for Plasma related packages:
#   * You need to enable "non-free" component on Debian GNU/Linux
#   * You need to enable "multiverse" component on Ubuntu
#   * You can use Plasma related packages only on amd64
sudo apt install -y -V libplasma-dev # For Plasma C++
sudo apt install -y -V libplasma-glib-dev # For Plasma GLib (C)
sudo apt install -y -V libgandiva-dev # For Gandiva C++
sudo apt install -y -V libgandiva-glib-dev # For Gandiva GLib (C)
sudo apt install -y -V libparquet-dev # For Apache Parquet C++
sudo apt install -y -V libparquet-glib-dev # For Apache Parquet GLib (C)

R -e "install.packages('arrow')"
```