# How do I install the arrow package on RStudio Cloud with lz4 support?

Tags: r, rstudio, apache-arrow

I have a problem similar to this [RStudio community post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-cloud-installs-arrow-package-without-support-for-compression-or-s3/95767) and to [this stack overflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63096059/how-to-get-the-arrow-package-for-r-with-lz4-support)

I have tried the solutions presented in both cases. I still cannot get arrow installed with lz4 support. I am trying to be able to use `arrow::read_feather()` which requires lz4 support.

After following the instructions in the first solution, I get the following error when trying to load the arrow package.

```
> library(arrow)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘arrow’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/rstudio-user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/arrow/libs/arrow.so':
  libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas on how to install arrow with lz4 support in RStudio Cloud?

Comment: Have you tried to install arrow with `Sys.setenv(LIBARROW_MINIMAL = FALSE); install.packages("arrow", type = "source")`? That will build arrow from source and install many of the optional extra packages. Setting `Sys.setenv(ARROW_R_DEV = TRUE)` will give you verbose output.

I've tried to replicate this on RStudio Cloud, and I am getting the same error when using RSPM binaries. Given the error that `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` can't be opened and lookintg at what libssl is installed on RStudio Cloud (libssl1.1) I suspect there's a mismatch of versions between the RSPM binary and RStudio Cloud.

Comment: @JonKeane, When I try installing with this method I get 
`*** Successfully retrieved C++ source`
`*** Building C++ libraries`
`**** cmake`
`**** arrow`
`**** Error building Arrow C++. Re-run with ARROW_R_DEV=true for debug` `information.`
`------------------------- NOTE ---------------------------`
`See https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/install.html`
`for help installing Arrow C++ libraries`
`---------------------------------------------------------`

Comment: @JonKeane adding thw verbosity allowed me to finally find the error in the install. +1 !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @JonKeane and his answer to my [jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-12742?filter=-2#)

I was able to use

```
Sys.setenv(LIBARROW_BINARY = TRUE); install.packages('arrow', type = "source")
```

to solve this issue.